# Hospedagem de aplicação Ruby com Sinatra

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel, sinatra

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Ruby com a DSL Sinatra. 
Para isso instalei o Node.js em seguida o ruby com Sinatra.

Minhas aplicações localmente estão funcionando normalmente. Porém gostaria de deixa-las disponíveis para consulta web. (para que possa realizar a chamada em qualquer local).

Alguém terias algum manual de primeiros passos? Este tipo de aplicação é possível deixa-las em servidores web compartilhados ? (Hospedagem de sites com CPanel) ?

Muito Obrigado e Sucesso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você precisa testar pequenas aplicações Ruby, uma das maneiras mais simples é utilizar o Heroku. Com o plano grátis deles, é possível colocar algumas aplicações para testes. Veja em: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction

Comment: Anderson, obrigado pelo auxilio. Realizei todos os procedimentos para subir a aplicação.
Porém como eu a executo ? Eu utilizava o comando "ruby system.rb -p8081 -e production"

Porem pelo heroku a pagina não responde. Teria alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Se você seguiu todos os passos, não precisa executar a aplicação,  o Heroku vai iniciar automaticamente a aplicação quando vc executar o comando "git push heroku master", conforme está descrito aqui: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app

Answer (score 0):

O [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) é o mais simples de resolver no curto prazo.

Se procura uma solução mais robusta e que possa ser até mais barata que o Heroku, procure pelo App Engine, do Google Cloud Platform com soluções de CI/CD utilizando uma ferramenta como Codeship ou Travis.

Tem um guia do Google específico para aplicações Rails, [veja](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine).

Para o banco de dados, se você usa PostgreSQL ou MySQL, recomendo na mesma infraestrutura, o Cloud SQL. Também tem um [guia completo para integrar com o Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/using-cloudsql-postgres).

Muito se fala da Amazon Web Services, onde você vai encontrar um serviço bom, mas que pode te dar dores de cabeça em auto-escala. Existem comparações entre [Heroku e AWS](https://hackernoon.com/aws-vs-heroku-cloud-platform-comparison-for-2017-5f2194c0673e?gi=ef3baaacb6e9) que possam te dar um norte melhor.